# Does cURL support FXP (Site2Site Transfer)

Tags: curl, libcurl

Wikipedia article says that cURL does not support FXP(File eXchange Protocol).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_FTP_client_software

I'm using libcurl. Is there any workaround to achieve Site2Site(FXP) with libcurl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, libcurl does not support that feature. It actually used to at one point in time several years ago, but the functionality was removed in a restructure and due to the fact nobody bothered to take care of the code.

It is not something you can work-around easily, no.